# UIMA RUTA extend wordlist at runtime

Tags: ruta

I am using a UIMA RUTA SCRIPT to match person names in a WORDLIST.
The wordlist is read from a resource folder which is declared when creating the RutaEngine:

```
 WORDLIST SamplePersonNames = 'per_names.txt';
 DECLARE NameAnnotation;
 MARKFAST(NameAnnotation, SamplePersonNames, true);
```

Is it possible to expand that list at runtime, e.g. when a user might want to add additional names?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to activate the reloading of the wordlist for each process() call by setting the parameter 'reloadScript', or you could use/adapt the MARKFASTRELOAD from ruta-core-ext, which is not completely functional in the latest release.

*DISCLAIMER: I ama developer of UIMA Ruta*

Answer (score 0):

What we did is adding a filewatch to the directory with all the ruta scripts and resource files (word lists).

If one of the files changed, a complete new RUTA engine is loaded and initialized (by sending a fragment of data into the engine). If everything was successful we replace the active engine with the new initialized engine. Because we do that in a background task, there is no performance penalty.
If you have large wordlists it takes some time to initialize (will be done at the first call to it).

I have no idea of that could be a good solution for your scenario. In our situation it makes development of rules much easier, because there is no need to restart the engine.